# (550, b'5.7.1 You are not allowed to send messages as "webmaster@localhost"')}

Tags: django

Сайт на django. При попытке отправить письмо на сервере возникает ошибка.

```
(550, b'5.7.1 You are not allowed to send messages as "webmaster@localhost"')}
```

Вроде бы сделал все по документации и как было указанно в инструкции хостинга, но все равно не работает.
Вот мой **settings.py**:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.timeweb.ru'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TSL = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'login'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

Что может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Стоит задать настройки `SERVER_EMAIL` и `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`. В ошибке написано, что MTA не позволяет отправлять вам почту с адреса webmaster@localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Такая же проблема была с gitlab при попытке отправить почту с timeweb
успешно победил с помощью инициализации переменной gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from']